# Calculus distance maximizing

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Point $(x, y)$ satisfies the inequality $x^4 + y^2 \leqslant 1$. Determine the largest possible distance from the origin for $(x, y)$.

So the largest distance will result when $x^4+x^2=1$.

The distance from the origin for point $(x,y)$ is $d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but from the given inequality we see that $y^2=1-x^4$ therefore we get $d(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1-x^4}$. I know that in order to maximize distance we should find the derivative of $d(x)$, but it seems rather peculiar to differentiate that expression. Is there another way I could go with this?

Comment: $d$ is minimized if and only if $d^2$ is minimized, so you can do without the square root when you take the derivative.

Comment: What's wrong with differentiating that?

Comment: To differentiate $d=(x^2+1-x^4)^{\frac12}$ you just have to apply the chain rule. This is not difficult.

Comment: Nothing. It's just that this question was on our exam and the time/question ratio was relatively bad to start manipulating that.

Comment: @Nick Is that true in general or am I missing something?

Comment: If you apply the chain rule then only the $\textrm{numerator}$ plays a role when you set the derivative equal to zero which is the derivative of the inner function.

Comment: Yes, it's true in general. The function $f(x) = x^2$ is monotonically increasing when $x > 0$. So if $x_1 < x_2$, then $x_1^2 < x_2^2$ and vice versa.

Comment: It should not be difficult to differentiate at all.

Comment: Even if you don’t know the trick of looking at $d^2$, that is a very straightforward derivative that should not take much time to compute.

Comment: Note you need to convince yourself that the distance function won't be maximized on the interior of the region $y^2 + x^4 \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. You're after the maximim of $d$ in the region $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid f(x,y)\leqslant1\}$, where $f(x,y)=x^4+y^2$. That maximum cannot be attained in the region $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid f(x,y)<1\}$ because that's an open set and therefore if the maximum was attained there, it be attained at a critical pont of $d$. But the only critical point of $d$ is $(0,0)$ and $d$ has actually a minimum there.

So, you can use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum in the region  $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid f(x,y)=1\}$. To do so, you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{\partial d}{\partial x}(x,y)=\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\\\frac{\partial d}{\partial y}(x,y)=\lambda\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\\f(x,y)=1\end{array}\right.\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}2x=4\lambda x^3\\2y=2\lambda y\\x^4+y^2=1.\end{array}\right.$$Its solutions are $(\pm1,0)$, $(0,\pm1)$, $\pm\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$ and $\pm\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2,-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$. The value that $d$ takes at the first four of these points is $1$, in the remainig ones it is $\frac54$.

Therefore, the minimal distance is $\frac{\sqrt5}2$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating the square of $d$, we get $2x-4x^3=0\implies x=0\lor \pm\sqrt2/2$.

Those are the critical points, and we get $1$ and $\sqrt5/2$ when we evaluate.

So the maximum distance is $\sqrt5/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

Constraint: $x^4+y^2 \le 1$;  $y^2\le 1-x^4;$

Maximize : $x^2+y^2\le x^2+1-x^4=$

$-(x^4-x^2)+1=$

$-[(x^2-1/2)^2-1/4]+1=-(x^2-1/2)^2+5/4\le 5/4$.

Maximum attained at $x^2=1/2$;

$y^2=5/4 -1/2=3/4.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(a,b)$ be the point on $x^4+y^2=1$. At the maximal distance from the origin $O$, $OP$ is normal to the curve, i.e.

$$y’= -\frac{2a^3}{b}=-\frac ab  \implies a^2=\frac12,\>\>\>b^2=\frac34$$

Thus, the maximal distance is 
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\frac{\sqrt5}2$$